# How to gem install mysql with ruby version 1.8.4?

Tags: mysql, ruby

I need to install mysql on the system. As usual I typed in gem install mysql. Instantly got an error message: "mysql requires Ruby version >= 1.8.6" Current version is at 1.8.4. Considering it's a company's server, it's not easy to upgrade Ruby in a short time (people are afraid their stuff will be broken and it needs a special approval etc). What's a simple way for me to get around it and install mysql there? I don't need a latest version, just some mysql driver is probably enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [main gem](http://www.tmtm.org/en/mysql/ruby/) requires higher than 1.8.4

But there's [another module from MySQL](http://www.tmtm.org/en/ruby/mysql/) but not installed in the same way. And it requires 1.8.2 So you should be able to use that.